# Output alpha/numeric/alphanumeric text with grep

Tags: grep

I have a single line of text containing 12k of these blocks separated by a comma:

```
{"hash":"AbCD1QS","title":"","description":"","width":1920,"height":1080,"size":12345689,"ext":".jpg","animated":false,"prefer_video":false,"looping":false,"datetime":"2009-01-04 02:32:61"}
```

The "alphanumeric" text next to hash can also be all lowercase, all uppercase, contain no numbers, or contain all numbers.

How do I output just the text next to hash using Grep, and each result to a new line?

Comment: Please add your desired output to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep -Po "(?<=hash\":\")[^\"]*"
```

`-P` for using perl regular expressions

`(?<=hash\":\")` matches string after *hash":"*

`[^\"]*` matches any characters til the quote mark

Answer (score 0):

Use a JSON parser for JSON data:

```
$ json='{"hash":"AbCD1QS","title":"","description":"","width":1920,"height":1080,"size":12345689,"ext":".jpg","animated":false,"prefer_video":false,"looping":false,"datetime":"2009-01-04 02:32:61"}'
$ echo "$json" | jq -r '.["hash"]'
AbCD1QS
```